# getting an error when running in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was working on selenium... I was able to locate elements in fb and gmail and when I try to run the same code with my project I was getting an error as element not visible. My error is:

> Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`: element not visible

when I try to find the `elementByName` or `elementByID`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("abhinai");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("abhinai");
```

the code for finding element when I use firebug tool is

```
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitValidationTextBox dijitTextBoxError dijitValidationTextBoxError dijitError dijitTextBoxHover dijitValidationTextBoxHover dijitTextBoxErrorHover dijitValidationTextBoxErrorHover dijitErrorHover dijitHover" id="widget_firstName" role="presentation" lang="en" widgetid="firstName"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="firstName" type="text" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" id="firstName" placeholder="required" value="" aria-invalid="true"></div></div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div>
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"> </div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="firstName" type="text" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" id="firstName" placeholder="required" value="" aria-invalid="true"></div>
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="firstName" type="text" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" id="firstName" placeholder="required" value="" aria-invalid="true"> </div>
```

can anyone help me

Comment: `WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));``

Comment: Hi Gurey i was not asking how to increase time for the element, i am unable to pass text into the field which is possible in fb and gmail but unable to pass through my application

Comment: Okay, sorry for not explaining enough. Sometimes, elements are not visible because the javascript has not executed yet. In these cases you need to wait for the element to be visible. There are also another alternative, if you try to findElements instead of findElement and then loop through the array and interact with the object that .isDisplayed().

Comment: u are making the answer very complex as i think this will be an easy answer but i was wrong on some attribute i think... if its a login page do we use loops

Comment: Waiting can make sense if async JS occurs, but maybe you have another elements with same ID? `findElement()` returns the first one it finds from top so if you have in your HTML other elements with same Id that are hidden, you may be interacting with them.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the link of the webpage.and when referring other persons use @Gurey or @ whoever the person is to notify them

Comment: By chance is your login dialog in an iframe? If so, you'll need to switch to that iframe before finding the element.